# what class type should s be in after s has been resolve by for(auto &s :text)?

Tags: c++, string, char, auto

```
string text("asdffffffffff.f");
for (const auto &s : text){
  cout << s ;
  if(s.empty() || s[s.size()-1] == '.')
      cout << endl;
  else
        cout << "" ;
  }
return 0;
};
```

1. My book doesn't state what text should be, so I made the string text up, but what type should text be? const string, const char, something else?

   2. After resolve, what type does s becomes?
   3. what is s[s.size()-1] ? or what function type is s attempting to call for both empty and size?
      -After compiling I get an error: 'empty and size in 's,' which is of non-class type 'const char.
   4. When I look though string and char function in my book, I couldn't find an empty() or size() function. Do I have to make the function empty() and size()?

Comment: If text is defined as you showed then s has referenced type const char & and the code will not compile. Otherwise define text as for example std::vector<std::string> In this case s will have type const std:;string &.

Comment: Easy trick: given `for ([qual] auto x [suf] : y)`, the type of `x` always equals `[qual] decltype(*y.begin()) [suf]`.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: Yeah, "easy".

Comment: Here's [one example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ccb9d8dc23b6c0b) of a trick to get compilers to print the type of something. You can also modify it a bit to have it work for [template type deduction](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea7b40f8c4d681a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case auto is deducted to type char, so `s` is `const char&`.

To fix your code you can write :

```
    for (const auto& s : text){
    cout << s ;
    if(s == '\0' || s == '.')
        cout << endl;
    else
        cout << "" ;
}
```

`'\0'` represents an empty char. You don't have to write a function.
`'\0'` also acts as a string terminator, so every string and char* contains a `'\0'` at the end that is appended automatically for you.

`empty()` and `size()` are member functions of the `std::string` class.
text is an `std::string` so you can use `text.empty()` or `text.size()` `.size()` returns the total size of the string.

However `s` is not an array here (it's a single reference to a `char`, not a `char*`) so you can't use `operator []` with a single `char`.